# How to set titles to lmplots according to cateogorical variable?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, classification, seaborn

I need to plot a sns lmplot of two quantitative variables according to a qualitative variable (sex). When I add hue and col arguments as follows:

```
g = sns.lmplot(x = "exper", y = "wage", hue = "female",col = "female", data = df, sharey = False)
```

it all works out. Yet instead of titling each plot as female = 0 and female = 1, I want to title them as Men and Women. To do so, I tried a loop:

```
for i in df["female"]:   
    if i == 0:
        g.set_titles(col_template = "Men")
    else:
        g.set_titles(col_template = "Women")
```

But it yields Men on both plots. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach uses `g.axes[row, column].set_title(...)`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1234)
df = pd.DataFrame({"exper": np.random.randint(1, 11, 50),
                   "wage": np.random.randint(100, 200, 50),
                   "female": np.random.randint(0, 2, 50)})
df["wage"] += df["exper"] * 10
g = sns.lmplot(x="exper", y="wage", hue="female", col="female", data=df, sharey=True)
g.axes[0, 0].set_title("Male")
g.axes[0, 1].set_title("Female")
g.axes[0, 1].tick_params(labelleft=True) # to set the ticks when sharey=True
g.fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: lmplot with changed titles]

Another approach is to temporarily rename `0` to `male` and `1` to `female`. And also change the column name from `female` to `gender`:

```py
df1 = df.replace({"female": {0: "male", 1: "female"}}).rename(columns={"female": "gender"})
g = sns.lmplot(x="exper", y="wage", hue="gender", col="gender", data=df1, sharey=True)
g.axes[0, 1].tick_params(labelleft=True)
g.fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: renaming the elements to change an lmplot]